# How to exclude text from `<script>` tag within the HTML DOM when calling `element.getText()`

Tags: java, selenium, dom, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm using selenium on Java to test HTML page. Here's an example of HTML:

```
<a>
  Return to homepage
  <script>
    <form>...</form>
  </script>
</a>
```

I need to get text of `<a>` element to check that it's correct.

Chrome, Firefox, IE and Edge return me correct text (`Return to homepage`) when I call `element.getText()` for this `<a>` element, but Safari returns me also the text which is located inside `<script>` tag (which is not text, but HTML code)

**Is there a way I can exclude content of `<script>` when I call `element.getText()` for my `<a>` element?**

This happens only in Safari (latest browser and driver version)

Comment: The `<script>` tag should not have HTML elements inside of it. That way lies madness. Move the `<form>` out of the `<script>` tag.

Comment: @BobDalgleish, I don't have access to application and can't change it's code, so this isn't the solution for me. Maybe you know the way to exclude content of `<script>` or the way to get only top-level text of html element in selenium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have already identified the *WebElement* as **element** next you can take help of [**`executeScript()`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html#executeScript-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) method to extract the text **Return to homepage** as follows :

```
String myText = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].firstChild.textContent;", element);
```

Comment: thanks for you help, this script helped me to get the correct text.